# links are broken after install my web application built with asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, routes

I was developing a web site for some time using mvc 3 and after deploy it in production nothing work because all the urls written the using Url.Action method are wrong. For example, 
I have this code:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Add", "Persona")){ ...
```

this is the result in Dev:

```
<form action="/SIIJYP/Modulos/Personas/Naturales/Persona/Add" method="post">
```

and this is the result once deployed:

```
<form action="/SIIJYP/r.ashx/Personas?action=Add&amp;controller=Persona" method="post">
```

What can be causing that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What version of IIS is the production environment running on?

If you are running on IIS 6 then Phil Haack has a good rundown (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) on what settings you need to perform (as does the [asp.net/mvc](http://asp.net/mvc) website)

Comment: It is running on IIS version 7 and the problem was in its configuration. Sadly, I don´t know what was wrong. It was solved importing the configuration from another well-configured machine.